# Pie Chart for Dynamic values in ios

Tags: pie-chart, ios8.4

I am beginner in iOS development .I am developing an application and I want create *pie chart* using dynamic data from *JSON*.

Data will looks like:

```
   {
    "name": "Sales",
    "total_earning": "904006",
    "per": 40.41
     },
    {
    "name": "Service",
    "total_earning": "596845",
    "per": 26.68
    }
```

I want display *"per"* in *pie chart* and it's dynamic values.
Can you tell me which is the best way?

[This pie chart for Department wise Earning Report in Android I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmGBQ.png)

Comment: improve your formatting

Comment: How to implement pie chart any one know .?kindly replay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dlpiechart](https://github.com/dilipajm/piechart) class of dilipajm in **GitHub**, then, modify property & var for your purpose. Hope its useful.

Comment: Thank You it work for me @nik ,but  in slices of pie chart display integer value ,77.68 it display only 77 .Could you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: @JaywantKhedkar : in DLPieChart.m file, find method     **- (CGFloat)pieChart:(DLPieChart *)pieChart valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index** {}   , then modify line below:  return [[self.DLDataArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue];   to:   return [[self.DLDataArray objectAtIndex:index] **floatValue** ];   Hope its helpful.

Comment: I had modified return [[self.DLDataArray objectAtIndex:index] floatValue ]; but still facing same problem ,When I change return value it show me round off value i.e 77.68 it show me like 78.Could you have any idea how I can fix that .

Comment: @JaywantKhedkar: in DLPieChart.m, find method **- (void)updateLabelForLayer:(SliceLayer *)pieLayer value:(CGFloat)value** {} , then change: @"%0.0f" to: @"%.2f". Hope its useful.

Comment: @Nik : How can i remove side boxes

Comment: @sabir: you mean that removing legend of piechart? In DLPieChart.m, comment out line 706 below:   // [self drawLegends:layerHostingView dataArray:dataArray];